# Intellij idea remote debug for javascript

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

When I debug javascript using Intellij, I only get a copy of target [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQY5V.png). But what if I want to debug the local file directly, what should I do? Here is a capture of my [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dmpi.png).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when using Intellij javascript debuger, for example starting tomcat server with javascript debuger then you can set break point only into target js files. src file breakpoint don't work.